# How to make a GET call by executing a javascript file and print response in terminal

Tags: javascript

So I am using python for all needs in my life and have never touched javascript. Now I might need to learn javascript because of certain reasons.

First thing that came to my mind is to try to make a GET call and print the response body. I seem to have trouble finding the answer for this questions.

I want to have a javascript file called `get.js`. Then I want to run the file by `node get.js` and print the response body to terminal.

I basically want this translated from python to javascript:

Python script:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("http://ip.jsontest.com/")

print r.text
```

In terminal:

```
$ python get.py
{"ip": "80.147.208.248"}
```

Comment: Need to be more specific. Would be different approach for browser vs node.js server for example. Also what research have you done? This isn't a code writing service

Comment: @charlietfl no browser. I want to run this file from terminal and print the output to terminal.

Comment: not hard to search how to make requests in node

Comment: @charlietfl I was searching for how to do it with javascript. Adding "node" keyword in my search helped :)

Answer (score 0):

So this seems to be the way. I needed to search for "node get request" not "javascript get request".

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: 'ip.jsontest.com',
  path: '/'
};

callback = function(response) {
  var str = '';

  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
  });
}

http.request(options, callback).end();
```